# How can I check if the stream is online or not?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I know how to test if the stream is online with the API ?

Because I want to put a Red circle in my menu if the the stream is online !

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you speak of a live stream ? (your question is not very detailed !) 
Then you can check the `onair` field that will tell you this: the value is true if the live stream is broadcasting and watchable in the player.